# MYSQL trigger: delete row from another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've got a table that I'm trying to set up for auto-processing updates to a linking table.

When a row is added to the auto-processing table (and there's logic in place for when that happens or doesn't happen), it adds a row that table and then a MySQL Trigger takes over.

The trigger is:

```
delimiter //

create trigger trg_auto_processing after insert on link_auto_processing
for each row
BEGIN
    -- pause
    do sleep(2);

    -- update link_table
    insert ignore into link_table (col_1, col_2) VALUES (NEW.col_1, NEW.col_2);
    delete from link_table where col_1 = NEW.col_1 and col_2 != NEW.col_2;
            
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

When testing this, the row is added to `link_auto_processing` table just fine, the trigger activates and it does the insert into `link_table`, but it doesn't do the delete.

To my understanding, it can't be a table-lock because it did the insert, So what am I missing here? I've tried putting the delete in a "before insert" trigger on the `link_auto_processing` table, but that doesn't work either.

I've even tried just updating the `link_table` with the trigger but that also doesn't work.

Insert works.
Delete doesn't work.
Update doesn't work.

Can't figure out why. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your code will not work with null-values (inserted or existing). Apart from that, it looks as if the code should do what you describe. Can you create an example that will reproduce your problem (e.g. create statements for 2 tables, the trigger, some sample data and an insert that will not work correctly)? You can testrun it e.g. on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0. Something either in your code or your data is different from what we assume it is, so a verifiable example helps figuring that out.

Comment: Are there any triggers on link_table? If so are they behaving as expected?

Comment: There's no triggers on the link_table. It turns out there's a timing issue, where the row it needs to delete doesn't exist yet, and doesn't exist until after the trigger completes (regardless of any delay I add). I ended up solving the problem with a stored procedure and an event.